# Which country has the largest number of non-immigrant ethnic groups recognized by the country?

Tags: international, demographics

> Soon after the establishment of the People's Republic of China, 39
> ethnic groups were recognized by the first national census in 1954.
> This further increased to 54 by the second national census in 1964,
> with the Lhoba group added in 1965. The last change was the addition
> of the Jino people in 1979, bringing the number of recognized ethnic
> groups to the current 56. The following are the 56 ethnic groups
> (listed by population) officially recognized by the People's Republic
> of China.[7]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ethnic_groups_in_China

> A number of ethnic groups of the People's Republic of China are not
> officially recognized.[1] Taken together, these groups (Chinese:
> 未识别民族; pinyin: wèi shíbié mínzú) would constitute the twentieth most
> populous ethnic group of China. Some scholars have estimated that
> there are over 200 distinct ethnic groups that inhabit China,[1]
> compared to 56 groups are officially recognized. There are in addition
> small distinct ethnic groups that have been classified as part of
> larger ethnic groups that are officially recognized. Some groups, like
> the Hui of Xinjiang with the Hui of Fujian, are geographically and
> culturally separate, except for the shared belief of Islam. Han
> Chinese, being the world's largest ethnic group, has a large diversity
> within it, such as in Gansu, whose Han individuals may have genetic
> traits from the assimilated Tangut civilization.[citation needed]
> Although they are indigenous to Hainan island and do not speak a
> Chinese language, the Lingao (Ong-Be) people near the capital (8% of
> the population) are counted as Han Chinese.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrecognized_ethnic_groups_in_China

China has over 56 recognized non-immigrant ethnic groups, and some scholars have estimated that there are over 200 distinct ethnic groups that inhabit China. I was wondering what was the country that had the largest number of native ethnic groups (not recent immigrants) in the world, because although 200 is a large number I don't think China would be number 1. It would probably be in the top 5 though.

Comment: I do think that the clarification "recognized by the country" does make this question answerable and non-opinion-based.

Comment: What does "native" mean in the context of the question? The 56 recognised ethnic groups in China include, for example, Tatar, Uzbek, Russian and Vietnamese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prize probably goes to [Papua New Guinea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papua_New_Guinea), because: "There are hundreds of ethnic groups indigenous to Papua New Guinea" who speak 851 languages, despite the fact that is has a population of only about 10 million people.

[Nigeria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nigeria) with more than 525 languages spoken among its 230 million people is probably the runner up.

[India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/India), with a population of 1.4 billion people, where 447 languages are spoken, is probably in third place.

The number of [ethnic groups in Brazil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil) is probably under 150 (counting each of about sixty uncontacted tribes as a separate ethnic group and considering another 60 significant immigrant populations) among its roughly 203 million people, which is probably less than the other three top contenders and is probably also less than the roughly 200 ethnic groups in the People's Republic of China (which is probably in fourth place), leaving Brazil in fifth place.

There is an inherent definitional issue of lumping v. splitting ethnic group definitions, but treating separate languages as each having at least one ethic group of its own seems like as  reasonable a way as any to achieve a consistent definition of ethnic groups on a global basis.

Comment: I don't think langauge is a useful way to identify ethnic groups.  Scots speak English... this doesn't mean that Scots are English.  There is no more agreement about what is a language and what is a dialect than there is about what is an ethnic group

Comment: Also, are French-speaking Swiss a different ethnic group versus France-French people? There are some cultural differences, but opinions will differ as to whether these differences are enough to split them vs lump them. The German dialect of modern-day Pennsylvania Germans is significantly different to what most people speak today in Germany - does that mean that there has been an ethnic split, or should we still lump both groups under a single "German" umbrella ethnicity?

Comment: But which ethnic groups in PNG are actually officially "recognized by the country"? If you ignore official recognition, then very likely the US (which has many immigrants from around the world including PNG/Nigeria/India/Brazil/China) has the most distinct ethnic groups.

Comment: @user103496 immigrants wouldn't count, though - the question was about ethnic groups *native* to the country.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov: Immigrants are allowed to have children and those children born in the country are then *native*